# Regex to match from position 13 to end of line

Tags: regex, expression

Example strings:

```
DFDBDFDFDF21R123
DFDBDFDFDF21DFD
```

I need a regex that when run matches ths following:

```
R123
DFD
```

**(no EOL chars)**

Thanks, I hope there is a simple solution that my brain isn't conjuring.

Comment: I think you mean position 12 to the end of the line, seeing as an index of 0 is much more common than an index of 1.

Comment: I said this in my answer, but I think it's worth using a substring function instead of regex. Pretty much all languages have this function.

Answer (score 9):

```
/^.{12}(.*)$/
```

The first part will look for the first 12 characters and throw them out, and the second part will group the rest.

Edit: as others have pointed out, you really should just use substring in whatever language you're using. Regex is overkill.

Comment: ...but in some specific cases this is the only way. Question is there a way to match the exact start and end char position given `^` and `$` with chart start and end values? (I would say no, but with regex you never know... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/.{12}(.*)/
```

Match the first 12 chars, then match the rest.

But I agree with @chance: `substr` would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a substring function in your language instead.

If you REALLY want a regex solution, in spite of it being about a hundred times slower and more complex than you really need, try something like this:

```
/.{12}(.*)/
```

Your desired result is then in the first capture group.